# find peak values in matlab

Tags: matlab

suppose that we are determine peaks  in  vector  as follow:
we have real values one dimensional vector  with length  m,or
x(1),x(2),.....x(m)
if   x(1)>x(2)  then  clearly for first point peak(1)=x(1);else  we are then comparing  x(3)  to x(2),if x(3)

```
[ indexes,peaks]=function(x,m);
c=[];
b=[];
if  x(1)>x(2) 
    peaks(1)=x(1);
else

 for i=2:m-1
     if x(i+1)< x(i) & x(i)>x(i-1)
         peak(i)=x(i);
     end;
 end
end
end
```

peaks   are determined    also using following picture:
[image]

sorry for the second picture,maybe it is not  triangle,just   A and C are on straight line,but here peak is B,so  i can't continue  my code for  writing algorithm to find peak values  in my vector.please help me to  continue it

## updated.numercial example given

x=[2 1 3 5 4 7 6 8 9]
here because  first point is more then second,so it means that  peak(1)=2,then we are comparing 1 to  3,because 3 is more then 1,we now want to compare 5 to 3,it is also  more,compare 5 to 4,because 5 is more then 4,then it means that peak(2)=5,,so if we continue next peak is 7,and final peak would be  9
in case of first element is less then second,then we are comparing  second element to third one,if  second is more then  third and first  elements at the same time,then peak is second,and so on

Comment: No offense, but the description seems a bit sloppy. Can you try to rephrase your question, and possibly give a numerical example of a vector and the peaks in it? The drawings are not really clear.

Comment: What does a triangle have to do with a one-dimensional vector?

Comment: no i have drawn  using paint,it should not be triangle,it is  just points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function [peaks,peak_indices] = find_peaks(row_vector)
    A = [min(row_vector)-1 row_vector min(row_vector)-1];
    j = 1;
    for i=1:length(A)-2
        temp=A(i:i+2);
        if(max(temp)==temp(2))
            peaks(j) = row_vector(i);
            peak_indices(j) = i;
            j = j+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Save it as find_peaks.m

Now, you can use it as:

```
>> A = [2 1 3 5 4 7 6 8 9];
>> [peaks, peak_indices] = find_peaks(A)

peaks =

     2     5     7     9


peak_indices =

     1     4     6     9
```

This would however give you "plateaus" as well (adjacent and equal "peaks").

Comment: does it help me to  all case?by the way  how can i declare into function form?

Comment: @dato: Check the answer now. It's been edited to suit your example.

Comment: thank you,but what i need is that not only show indexes,but as well  it's value

Comment: @dato: I've edited my answer. It should exactly suit your needs now.

Comment: thanks  very  much my friend,i will ask  to my supervaisor,if  i  understood everything correclty,than thanks very much,if  something is wrong,i will update  my question.fine day  my friend

Comment: just question for curious,can i do it  using if  statment?

Comment: also does it  work for  situation,when  first element is more then  second one?

Comment: sorry when first element is not more then first

Comment: @dato: It will also work when the first element is smaller. As to using if statements, we already are. But if you mean that you don't want to use the `max` function, you could simply replace `if(max(temp)==temp(2))` by `if(temp(2)>=temp(1) && temp(2)<=temp(3))` for the exact same functionality or even `if(temp(2)>temp(1) && temp(2)<temp(3))` if you want to exclude "plateaus".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` to do the comparison and add two points in the beginning and end to cover the border cases:

```
B=[1 diff(A) -1]; 
peak_indices = find(B(1:end-1)>=0 & B(2:end)<=0); 
peaks = A(peak_indices);
```

It returns

```
peak_indices =
     1     4     6     9
peaks =
     2     5     7     9
```

for your example.

Answer (score 0):

findpeaks does it if you have a recent matlab version, but it's also a bit slow.

This proposed solution would be quite slow due to the for loop, and you also have a risk of rounding error due to the fact that you compare the maximal value to the central one instead of comparing the position of the maximum, which is better for your purpose.

You can stack the data so as to have three columns : the first one for the preceeding value, the second is the data and the third one is the next value, do a max, and your local maxima are the points for which the position of the max along columns is 2.

I've coded this as a subroutine of my own peak detection function, that adds a further level of iterative peak detection
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42927-find-peaks-using-scale-space-approach